# Solving $\frac{dy(t)}{dt} = y(t)^2-2 y(t)+2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the following ODE
$$
\frac{dy(t)}{dt} = y(t)^2-2 y(t)+2
$$
I'm having a tough time because the differential is in terms of $dt$.

My gut instinct is to integrate both sides, but to do, I would have to integrate the right hand side by $dt$, and would get a messy solution.

How do I do this?

Comment: Hint: Separation of Variables. Write and solve $\displaystyle\int  \dfrac{dy}{y^2 - 2 y + 2} = \int dt$.

Comment: ^ And then usual integration.

Comment: And, as one more bit of hint, note that $y^2-2y+2=(y-1)^2+1.$ Any substitutions that might help with that?

Comment: Thanks, I've solved it to arctan(y-1) = t. I need to find it y(t) however. Update: I've  rearranged some things and ended up with y = tan(t) + 1.

Does that sound right?

Comment: Don't forget your constant of integration! You should then have $$\arctan(y-1)=t+C.$$ Solve for $y.$

Comment: Okay, so including the constant of integration (thanks @CameronBuie!), I end up with

y = tan(t+C)+ 1

(Sorry for the lack of Jax/TeX, will learn properly in the next few weeks!)

Answer (score 2):

As per comments above and to give the question an answer..
$$
y' = y^2 - 2y + 2 = (y-1)^2 + 1
$$
thus change of variables $v = y-1$ leads to
$$
v' = v^2+1
$$
therefore
$$
\arctan v = t + C \implies v = \tan (t + C) 
$$
thus solution is
$$
y = 1 + \tan (t + C) 
$$